# Skip Android class (WorkManager) in a Unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I can't change project code, I can only write tests.
I have a function for testing:

```
fun funToBeTested() {
    ClasWithWorkManager().veryVeryBadFunc(TAG)
// a lot of code to be tested below
...
}
```

and class with WorkManager:

```
class ClasWithWorkManager() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun veryVeryBadFunc(tag: String) {
            WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag(tag)
            WorkManager.getInstance().pruneWork()
        }
    }
}
```

There are no Android class references in the rest of this func.
Can I somehow cover with **Unit** test all **funToBeTested()** except of its first line?
Right now I have obvious *WorkManager is not initialized properly.* problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup WorkManager test init helper using below code to prevent issue of "WorkManager is not initialized properly. problem" :

```
  val mockedContext = getInstrumentation().targetContext
    val config = Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
        .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
        .build()
    WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(mockedContext, config)
```

You need to add below dependency (Kotlin DSL) for work manager unit testing :

```
testImplementation("androidx.work", "work-testing", "2.8.1")
testImplementation("org.robolectric", "robolectric", "4.9")
testImplementation("io.mockk", "mockk", "1.13.3")
```

OR (Groovy based syntax)

```
testImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:2.8.1" 
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.9"
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.13.3"
```